# How do I change the drawing setting to show the objects filled?

Tags: flash-cs5

When I create drawing shapes I cant see any color or fill.  I know there is a setting that need to be changed so I can see them.  Here is a pick of what is happening on my screen:
[image]

I draw the shape and all I see is the green outline, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the screen on your timeline there is a green square on your layer, from the looks of it you have click that. This shows layers as outlines.